# Can't see how to compile a header file with /clr switch in a mixed class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr, header-files, mixed-code

When creating a mixed mode class, on compilation the header file complains that it needs to be complied with the /clr switch as it is a mixed mode class, however, I can't see any option to specifically compile that header with /clr from visual studio, and I don't want to set the entire project with a /clr flag,

Does anyone know how I can specify that this header file is compiled correctly with /clr?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't compile header files.  You compile the implementation (.cpp) files which subsequently 'include' these files.

Comment: So the .cpp file does have the /clr flag set but on compile vs errors that the .h file needs the /clr flag

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong. The header files shouldn't be compiled at all.

Comment: Please add the exact error that the compiler produces.

Answer (score 0):

Every cpp file that includes the header needs the /clr flag, not the header itself.